# Json parsing in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wants to display my Json string in to Textblock.

My C# code is:

```
namespace JsonDemo
{
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();


      WebClient wc = new WebClient();
      wc.DownloadStringAsync(
         new Uri("http://192.168.1.32/test/NadalApp.asmx/GetCityDetails"));
      wc.DownloadStringCompleted +=
         new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(
           wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,
 DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = e.Result.Replace("</string>", "");
        str = str.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", "");
        str = str.Replace("<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">", "");
        Debug.WriteLine("Web service says: " + str);

    }
```

I got my json string on e.Result through web services. now how can i parse my string and display textblock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a JSON Parser for C#

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: worm:but when i m decentralize my object it gives error like do not conver json string.please give me some instruction how i convert my json string

Comment: @ FaddishWorm: actually i tryed to upload image but i dont have 10 reputation so it will be not possible.

Comment: @ FaddishWorm:please see bellow print out and give me answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]
hello FaddishWorm please see image this exeption occure.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the link [Json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and paste your JSON data there, it will generate the suitable C# classes for you. Copy those classes into your project and then use the JsonConvert class.

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: :thanks but when i tryed this one it gives exception like:: Could not load type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC'.